# can not import pydot even after installing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, pydot

When I try to install pydot it says that I have already installed it.

[image: it says that I have already installed pydot]

But whenever I try to import it I get an error saying :
Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.

This is my code:

```
model.summary()
import pydot
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

I am using python 3.6.3 on jupyter notebook.

Comment: How are you running the code? What is the output of `python -c import sys; print(sys.path)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the msi version of graphviz from >http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php

> add C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin to my system variables in PATH